# Extended Golay Code - Vectors of Odd Weight

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

> In V(24,2) every vector of odd weight is at distance at most 3 from some code-word in $G_{24}$, the extended binary golay code.

This seems to be a known result appearing in many texts and papers, stated perhaps differently - "The extended binary golay code is a semi\quasi-perfect code", however I could not find any proof of it.

Trying to prove it on my own, I relied on the fact that $G_{23}$ is a perfect code, and that it is enough to prove it for odd weights lesser than $12$, as $G_{24}$ has the codeword **1**, so the complementary weights and code-words complete the proof immediately.

For vectors of weight $1,3$ it is obvious as $G_{24}$ has the codeword **0**. For vectors of weight 5, I claimed that in $G_{23}$ there is a codeword either of weight 8 with distance 3 from said vector, and then extending both the vector of weight 5 and the codeword of weight 8 by adding a 0 component will get me to a codeword in $G_{24}$ and a vector of weight 5 in V(24,2), or a codeword of weight 7 with distance 2 from said vector, and then extending the vector of weight 5 by a component 0 and the vector of weight 7 by a component 1 will lead me to a codeword of weight 8 in $G_{24}$ in distance $\le3$ from the vector of weight 5 in V(24,2).

Following the same logic, it can be shown for weights 7,9 and 11. This proof would be valid if the mapping of the vectors of weight $i$ from V(23,2) to V(24,2) was a bijection, sadly it obviously isn't so - there are far more words of weight $i$ in V(24,2), so the proof is obviously lacking. I assume it is possible to overcome this issue with the fact that $G_{23}$ can be reached from $G_{24}$ by puncturing *any* fixed point, yet I can't see how.

Any hints on how to overcome this issue or any other methods of proof will be extremely appreciated!

Comment: The idea in your last paragraph is the key (+1 for that and the earlier reasoning). Let's take stock. You are looking at an odd weight vector $v\in V(24,2)$. Thus at least one of the components of $v$ is zero. Let's puncture $G_{24}$ at such a position! Unless I missed something else about your approach that should work, or?

Comment: Not necessarily. But if the codeword $w$ has a 1 in the punctured position, then it cannot be at distance $3$ from $v$, because the punctured version of $w$, call it $w'$ would have an odd weight, and thus be at an even distance from $v'$.

Comment: yes of course. thanks!

Comment: For clarification for future possible readers, inbetween @Jyrki first comment and second comment I wrote that it is always possible to puncture both the vector and the codeword at a fixed 0 position (not the case). For some reason it got deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of the comments (the question already described good ideas):

We shall use heavily the facts that

1. The Golay code $G_{23}$ is a perfect 3-error correcting code. In other words any binary vector of length 23 is at a Hamming distance $\le3$ from a uniquely determined codeword.
2. We get a code equivalent to $G_{23}$ by puncturing the extended Golay code $G_{24}$ at **any** of the 24 positions. This follows for example from the fact that the group of automorphisms of $G_{24}$ is transitive (it is in fact the 5-tuply transitive Mathieu group $M_{24}$, but that is overkill for the purposes of this question).

The **claim** is that given an odd weight binary vector $v$ of length $24$ there is a word $w\in G_{24}$ such that $d(v,w)\le3$.

**Proof.** Because $v$ is of an odd weight at least one of its components is $0$. Let us fix such a bit position, and puncture $G_{24}$ at that position. Let $v'$ be the resulting vector of $23$ bits. By fact 2 above the code $G_{24}'$ that we get by puncturing $G_{24}$ at this position is equivalent to $G_{23}$. By fact 1 there is a word $w'\in G_{24}'$ such that $d(v',w')\le 3$.

Let $w\in G_{24}$ be the word gotten from $w'$ by extending it (at the punctured position) with an overall parity check bit. I claim that $w$ works. Recall that all the words of $G_{24}$ have even weight. There are two cases according to the parity of the weight of $w'$.

1. If $w'$ has an even weight, then the punctured bits of both $w$ and $v$ are zero, so
   $$
   d(v,w)=d(v',w')\le3.
   $$
2. If $w'$ has an odd weight, then the puncture bit of $w$ is a one, so
   $$
   d(v,w)=1+d(v',w').
   $$
   At first sight it may look like we have a problem in that this Hamming distance may be too large. But recall that in this case both $v'$ and $w'$ have an odd weight, so their Hamming distance must be even. Thus $d(v',w')\le2$, and the claim follows in this case as well. **Q.E.D.**

---

It is good to play with arguments like above so that they become second nature.
This type of reasoning involving extending/puncturing/shortening a binary code comes up frequently.

Comment: No idea how I missed this answer up until today. Thank you very much for your time and effort in explaining the concepts and ideas behind the answers themselves, it is extremely helpful and valuable!

Comment: No big deal, @Studentmath. I didn't want to leave the question unanswered, so I wrote a summary of the comments. I was half-hoping you would do that, but decided to write one myself just in case the reasoning in the comments was not totally clear. If no answer is "accepted", the site software will periodically "bump" the question to the front page.